# What is Ingram micro API service integration, have any document for Ingram micro API services?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to generate an interspire module for Ingram Micro api services but i don't know what are the services are provide by Ingram Micro.

how can manage the products relation from Ingram services to end-users site,
and how to generate & manage orders.

Comment: Uhm, google? Read their site? Contact their support?

Answer (score 3):

Ingram sell only to IT resellers, never to end-customer but in some cases stores and ship to the end-customer in behalf of the resellers (same service than Shipwire + it can also provide additional inventory).

Generally, the Internet model is:

1. Ingram provides a file with all its products range to the reseller
2. The reseller loads this products list (and inventory) in his site
3. The end-user places orders on the reseller site (interspire's site if I understand what you have in mind) and legally, buys from the reseller.
4. The reseller orders the product to Ingram who will ship it directly to the end-user in behalf of the reseller (the name on the packing slip is the reseller's name, not Ingram Micro's name)

There are some variants where the reseller has also its inventory at Ingram's warehouse.

All these steps can be automated mainly with Webservices. For Europe, you should contact the European "E-commerce team". They are based in UK (the city is Milton Keynes but I do not have the email, sorry).

Comment: Hi Laurent... Thanks for your valuable information.......

Comment: We have any chance for getting the documentation about automate web-services from there sites or any other sources ?

Comment: We have contact the support team of Ingram micro but they have no proper respond, we need the XML APIs for integrate our system.

Comment: I do not think it is available on any site. Ask them the IM-XML manual. If the person you get on the phone does not know what it is, it is not the e-commerce support (don't ask to the commercial team, they won't be able to answer).

Comment: Hi Laurent,  Thanks for your helpful information.....

Answer (score 0):

Ingram micro exposes a lot of services mainly by web service of flat files.:
- Price
- Inventory level
- Order status
- Order create
- Invoices...
Can you be more specific on what you try to achieve and in which country (Ingram Micro operates in 35 countries) ?

Comment: can you tell me first, what is the Ingram micro actually doing, its like ShipWire warehouse services or only reseller services?

Comment: We need to use the Ingram micro services for European countries.